# How to remove three styles from HTML table while cloning a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script which takes rows from an existing table in an ASP.net page and opens a new window with the table.

One of the cell in the ASP.net table has a DIV inside which forces anything extra to be removed and shows only "...". When the user hover overs, it displays the entire text with JavaScript.

Here is a sample of the table cell:

```
<td class="bodyNotLast vTop">
    <div style="width: 155px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
        <span id="lblEllipsis" title="
            Dr john;
            Dr. Mike;
            Dr. Kilt;
            Dr. Poland;
            Dr. James;
            Dr. Quint;
            Dr. Jose;
            Dr. Ashton;
            Dr. Giannis;
            Dr. Maroudis;
            ">
                Dr john;
                Dr. Mike;
                Dr. Kilt;
                Dr. Poland;
                Dr. James;
                Dr. Quint;
                Dr. Jose;
                Dr. Ashton;
                Dr. Giannis;
                Dr. Maroudis;
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Shows up like this:

[image]

The above works fine when viewing on the computer, because I can just hover over and it will show the rest of the text. When printing (creating the dynamic table in the script above).

How can I eliminate the following style: `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;` from each `TD` in the copy process, so the cell just expands to display everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Use this code when the new window is opened
$('.bodyNotLast .vTop div').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: What would be the way to use in JavaScript?

Comment: Is there any way I can do it inline with the code that is concatenating the `innerHTML`?

Comment: I'm rewriting my answer to better fit your question.

Comment: I can't seem to add `createBody.append("<script></script>");` keeps telling me unterminated string literals.

Comment: Actually I figured it out how to do it. I created a class instead of inline css and didn't send the class over to the new window and solved the problem!

Comment: Well I was going to ask if you could do that, or add a class to select, but I didn't know how much editing/control you wanted.

Comment: I will accept your answer any way for the heads up. and +1. Not sure why someone down voted my question but okay.